# Reposition the widget sidebar in Appearance->Widgets

Tags: widgets, admin, sidebar

Anyone know how to reposition the widget sidebars in the Widgets menu?[image]

Answer (score 0):

There will be a code inside your theme's `functions.php` file which registers the sidebars for you. You need to find it and rearrange the sidebars the way you want.

Open the `functions.php` file and search for `register_sidebar`. The sidebars are registered as an array inside this function.

Comment: When you say rearrange do you mean that the position on the screen is dependent on the position in the array?

Comment: Yes. Change the order of each sidebar in the `functions.php` to change it's visual place in the admin panel.

Comment: I am trying to remove it in the child theme so I do unregister_sidebar and then register_sidebar - will this cause any issues?

Comment: I don't think it would cause a problem as long as you preserve the original ID of the sidebars.